# How to know for sure if an Excel Function shall work in an Array Formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

There are hundreds of Built-in function in Excel. Is there any way to confirm if a built-in function shall essentially work in an Array Formula? For example I am unable to make RANK work in an Array Formula.  It seems (I may be wrong) it does not support Array Formula.

Where can I get any reference preferably say from Microsoft that clearly indicates if there are any Built-in Excel functions that essentially are not supported in an Array Formula? The Excel help is not that useful here.

It will help to decide if further debugging would be needed with my array formula or for sure it's not going to work.

Thanks

Comment: I happened to run across this problem with RANK() recently.  It will take 2 arrays as arguments, but only one of them can be calculated inside the function.  e.g. RANK(2*A1:A5,B1:B5,0) works correctly, but RANK(2*A1:A5,2*B1:B5,0) gives an error.

Comment: I know that doesn't answer your question, but it might help you use Rank() effectively.  I, too, have tried to find an exhaustive reference for functions that can use arrays, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

One thumb rule while computing always prevails,that whenever user needs to perform calculation which has either series of values or one value is suppose to generate many intermediate values, for this an object or a Data handler is required, which has Elements as many as Values, is basically called elements of the Variable or an ARRAY.

Every programming language provides command to declare Variable and an Array of Variable.

**For example in Visual Basic,**

Dim MyArray(2) as String

MyArray(0) = "A"

MyArray(1) = "AB"

We can use these elements if & when required as their Data type.

**Now returning to Excel**, here also fundamentals are similar. But Excel doesn't allows to declare Variable or an Array. Therefore Cell address can be used as elements either horizontally or vertically.

like simply write 5,6,7,8 & 9 in E1,F1,G1,H1 & I1. And write this CSE Formula in E3, {=SUM(E1:I1*{1,2,3,4,5})}, You get answer 115.

Excel calculates like E1*1 + F1*2 + G1*3 + H1*4 + I1*5 produce 5, 12, 21, 32, 45 equal to 115.

**TRANSPOSE** is always an CSE formula.

So the conclusion is whenever any such calculation is required Array Formula can be used. Popularly in Excel we call it CSE (Control+Shift+Enter) Formula.

I do hope above written text help you to decide when an Array Formula is required.

**Also, post your Rank Formula with related data you are struggling with I'll try to simplify it.**

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for the use of RANK.xx() in an array, I have worked around it by LARGE or SMALL with MATCH and a SEQUENCE.  I know that does not answer the question about "knowing if an Excel function will work in an array", but I don't have enough reputation to add a comment.

```
=LET( randmatrix, RANDARRAY( 12 ),
       MATCH( LARGE( randmatrix, SEQUENCE( 12 ) ), randmatrix, 0 ) )
```

The formula above generates a random string of numbers and then applies a rank to them.

This is a ridiculous solution to a made-up problem, but as you pointed out, this will not work:

```
=LET( randmatrix, RANDARRAY( 12 ),
       RANK.EQ( randmatrix, randmatrix ) )
```

The MATCH LARGE SEQUENCE illustrates the technique of emulating RANK by other means. I once faced this exact problem of RANK not working in an array, so I walked around it using this.